# How to fix Error in argument exception system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling, arguments

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;




namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pwnew.PasswordChar = '*';
            pwtxt.PasswordChar = '*';

            signup.Visible = false;

        }

        private void signupbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            signup.Visible = true;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (unnew.Text != null && pwnew.Text != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Connect obj = new Connect();
                    obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;
                    obj.conn.Open();
                    string insertuser = "insert into userTable('" + unnew.Text + "', '" + pwnew.Text + "')";
                    obj.cmd.Connection = obj.conn;
                    obj.cmd.CommandText = insertuser;
                    obj.conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Signup has been completed");
                    signup.Visible = false;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);


                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

        }

        private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (untxt.Text != null && pwtxt.Text != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Connect obj = new Connect();
                    obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;

                    obj.conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM userTable where username = '" + untxt.Text + "' and password '" + pwtxt.Text + "'", obj.conn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        Form2 meLoad = new Form2();
                        meLoad.Visible = true;
                        this.Hide();
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
                    }
                    obj.conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No empty fields are allowed");
            }
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I am completely new to c#, im having this error whenever i click sign up. It tells me to check the line 44 which is

```
try
                {
                    Connect obj = new Connect();
                    obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;
                    obj.conn.Open();
                    string insertuser = "insert into userTable('" + unnew.Text + "', '" + pwnew.Text + "')";
                    obj.cmd.Connection = obj.conn;
                    obj.cmd.CommandText = insertuser;
                    obj.conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Signup has been completed");
                    signup.Visible = false;

                }
```

Im a student, adn dont have enough background in programming, i'd appreciate someone's help. I really want to learn this programming language, and im currentlty having troubles.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU1TH.png) Thank u so much.

I use this for Connection

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Connect
    {
        public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        public string locate = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\hp\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\UserDB.mdf;'Integrated Security=True";
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace implies that the database connection is failing to parse the connection string.  Which you set here: `obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;`  What connection string are you using?

Comment: Try by follow simple tutorial on C#, before trying to use database

Comment: I did follow a tutorial on this, i just dont get it; we entered the same code but why am i getting errors if the tutorial didnt

Answer (score 1):

It seems something is breaking to connect your database.

Please double check your connection string,If you need help for connection string, you may visit https://www.connectionstrings.com/

This tutorial may be helpful for you to connect database using c#.

https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-access-database.html